# Show Careers2.0 remote jobs sorted by continents

Tags: feature-request, jobs

When looking for remote jobs, it is very common to find many jobs in the United States willing to offer remote work from any state into the USA, but not from abroad.

In the other hand, in Europe is very common to find the opposite, remote jobs offered from anywhere.

As a non US citizen, I would find useful a new feature in Careers 2.0 in order to filter remote jobs (or any kind of job offer actually) by continent, so I can focus on European job offers.

Comment: The "by continent" approach is only useful for Europe, where you can legally work more or less for any country in the bloc. Different story for Asia, South America, etc.

Comment: If not by continent, maybe it can be a checkbox to say, "US only" or "EU only" so that others don't waste time looking at the postings. With the number of jobs available it's quite frustrating sometimes.